How can I style the `button_to` tag to look exactly the same as `link_to`
would like to consult any css wizard in here on button_to styling for rails.
Context: I have a button_to :like and a link_to :comment sitting side by side (ideally I would like the like button to look exactly the same as the comment from a styling standpoint

But because rails apply some default styling to the button_to tag. It makes them look inconsistent across both button and like link, as per the image attached above.
What I have tried:

I have tried applying a CSS class to the button_to tag class: "remove_effect" and tried setting background: none and border: none but to no avail.
Decided to use link_to instead... but doesnt work even with method: :post. Apparently, it can only be used if i pass in some params as per this post: Using Rails link_to for links that post
Tried to convert my link_to to use a button_to instead, but I am not a fan of that as it seems like a deep compromise to make.

Question: What is the best approach to move forward with? Is there a way to tweak either the erb / HTML / CSS such thaat I can achieve the desired styling?
Alternatively, I can do the following, but would be last resort in case the above does not work:

Settle with some less ideal design not as I originally intended... e.g. applying some generic btn css class to both. Though I really want to give them the current look and feel (no border no background and the icon glows on hover, like this...



Have you tried using inline styles?

Add your css to the question and the form snippet

I don't know how you came to the conclusion "Apparently, it [link_to] can only be used if i pass in some params" which is nonsense. If you're using Turbo you need to use data: { turbo_method: :post } and you have to ensure that you don't have any script errors preventing Turbo/Rails UJS from working.
